# strange behavior when i use up arrow key in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

When I use my up arrow key to view previously run commands, I'm experiencing some strange behavior regardless of the terminal I use. I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04LTS with i3 window manager(regolith).

Below you will see an image of combined images tagged # according to how the commands appear when I hit the up arrow key.
The part tagged #1 is the command that first appears when I use the up arrow key and shows the correct output.

For the remaining images tagged #2,#3,#4, the commands I expect to see when I hit the up arrow key are `$TERM`, `exit` and `ls -lah`, respectively.

As you can see that's not the case.
There's a fragment of command #1 in all three commands.

Please help.

[image: A combination of 4 photos into 1 showing the different commands as they appear when I hit the up arrow key to see previously run commands]

Comment: What is your prompt set to now? (E.g., the output of `declare -p PS1`, or the lines mentioning `PS1` in your `.bashrc)

Comment: `declare -x PS1="\\e[0;36m[\\u@\\h \\W]\$ \\e[m "`
is the output of the command `declare -p PS1`

Comment: Apparently, you need to enclose the escape sequences in \[...\], to tell bash not to count them while determining the prompt width. Therefore, both the above PS1 and the following would work equally well:

PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\W]\$ \[\e[m\]'

Answer (score 0):

Reset your ~/.bashrc .
There is a default version of the .bashrc file in the /etc/skel/ directory in Ubuntu

Comment: i found an answer in a similar post. Thank you